# RedirectRequestTarget with hidden parameters possible?

Tags: java, url, wicket

I`m redirecting to an external URL in my wicket-application, example:

```
String returnUrl = "http://www.foo.no/bar/article262559.ece?rc=value";
getRequestCycle().setRequestTarget(new RedirectRequestTarget(returnUrl));
```

Now, the customer wants the parameter to be hidden from the users (as it is part of some paywall functionality). I know that you can`t use a normal redirect to accomplish this, but is there some other way to do it?

Cheers

Terje

Trondheim, Norway

Answer (score 2):

Is the customer happy for the system to be hacked? Because this looks entirely hackable.
You could however do this more securely by posting from the server to a web service on the remote server first, retrieving a reference from there to identify the post you just made, and passing this with the user's redirect instead.
That way the details are completely hidden from the client and much more secure.

Comment: It is hackable allright. Lets just say the userbase is not very knowledgeable of hacking. :) Anyway, thanks for the tip.